# How to parse JSON data through Retrofit, Coroutine with Kotlin in android studio

Tags: android, json, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm write code for JSON parsing, but JSON data is not retrieved. What would be the issue?

Below is the Data object class

```
data class UsersItem(
    val avatar_url: String,
    val events_url: String,
    val followers_url: String,
    val following_url: String,
    val gists_url: String,
    val gravatar_id: String,
    val html_url: String,
    val id: Int,
    val login: String,
    val node_id: String,
    val organizations_url: String,
    val received_events_url: String,
    val repos_url: String,
    val site_admin: Boolean,
    val starred_url: String,
    val subscriptions_url: String,
    val type: String,
    val url: String
)
```

Below is the List defined

```
class Users : ArrayList<UsersItem>()
```

Below is the ApiUtilities

```
object ApiUtilities {
    private val BaseURl = "https://api.github.com/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseURl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    }
}
```

Below is the ApiInterface

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/Users")
suspend fun getUsers(): Response<Users>
}
```

Below is the MainActivity,
I just tested to get the JSON Response with login id, but i'm not getting the result.
Please correct the code or give any suggestions

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val helloTxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt) as TextView
        val userApi = ApiUtilities.getInstance().create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val result = userApi.getUsers()
            if (result.isSuccessful && result.body() != null) {
                result.body()?.forEach {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${it.id}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("Manju", "${it.login}")
                    helloTxt.setText("${it.login}")
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using breakpoints or logs to see what's happening or what isn't happening ?

Comment: yes I tried breakpoints and logcat also, response is not getting

Comment: you only have `if (result.isSuccessful && result.body() != null) {` , where's your check for if the response isn't successful ?

Comment: I called instance of Retrofit and connected to server val userApi = ApiUtilities.getInstance().create(ApiInterface::class.java)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question : `where's your check for if the response isn't successful ?`

Comment: i'm not understanding the check, would you please tell what is check

Comment: did you try with `@SerializedName("")` in data classes? and can you see the response on the HTTP interceptor in the Logcat?

Comment: @SerializedName("") i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you schould use "/users" with small "u":

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/users")
suspend fun getUsers(): Response<Users>
}
```

insted of:

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/Users")
suspend fun getUsers(): Response<Users>
}
```